# How to create device-family-specific projects with Windows 10, like on W8.1/WP8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm planning to port my WP8.1 app to Windows 10 as a Universal app.
I saw that MS added the ability to create a single Universal project, and to create different family-specific folders that contain XAML pages/controls that share a single code-behind file. 
I *don't like* a few things about this approach though:

• I can only have different XAML files for different devices, but with the *same* .cs file, so it wouldn't be easy to create some device-specific UI logic, like animations and stuff

• Since I'd have a single Universal project, I'd have to check at *runtime* the availability of the APIs/classes I need, instead of being able to see whether I can use them or not at compile time, which is much better in my opinion.

I saw an MVA video where Jerry Nixon and Andy Wigley said that the classic multi-headed Universal projects would still be supported on Windows 10, but I have no idea on how to set them up, and I can't find a documentation anywhere.

Everybody's talking about this single project with shared .cs files, but I'd really feel more comfortable working with a multi-headed project: one for mobile phones, one for desktop/tablets, and possibly a *shared project* or some sort of PCL to share classes and stuff between the two projects (a shared project like with W8.1/WP8.1 would be awesome).

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: ot: not sure if the term 'family-specific' is the best choice..?

Comment: @TaW Yeah, I wouldn't know how to call it, since MS is always talking about "device family". As I said, what I mean is that I'd like to have a project for Desktop/Tablets and another one for mobile phones only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the Windows 8.1 Universal apps were build up from 3 projects. One for Windows 8.1 one for the Phone and a Shared CL.
Although there is no template built in for that you can achieve the same result by doing it manually, or create your own templet using the VS Extensibility tools.
All you need to do is Create a UAP solution, ad another UAP project, name it accordingly lets say MyProjectName.Phone and a Universal CL named as MyProjectName.Shared reference the shared project in the other two and you are ready to rock...

To target individual Device Families with your project you can specify that intent in the Package.Appmanifest.

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks! Is there an easy way to set the target device family for a specific project, so that they will run on their respective devices?
Also, since I'll end up having two separate binaries, how will I be able to submit them to the Store? I mean, will I be able to create a single app in the Store, upload the two binaries together, and will the Store automatically download the right binary depending on the device?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you specify the family your package will be offered only to that device family.

Comment: Thanks again! And can you confirm that the Store will accept different binaries for a single Universal app, and that it will automatically distribute the right one depending on the device trying to download the app?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to confirm this based on my own experience, but according to the documentation that I read soo far, yes, that is the case. I recon the experience will be the same like it is currently with the Win 8.1 Packages, you just upload multiple packages and a store will serve them accordingly what type of device is requested the download.

Comment: Sounds good! I just wonder how will some feature work using different binaries, for example, I guess continuum for phones won't be supported using separate projects, as the binary running on the phone will only be created for that device size and won't run in a window/full screen on another device.

Comment: This is why I do not recommend following this practice. If you are concerned about features that are not available on different devices you can check those APIs before you call them. The documentation is very extensive about Adaptive Code practices and I'm sure most of your concerns are addressed. I have been working on a UAP project my self and I have to say the experience is a lot better than used to be with the old Universal applications. Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt244352.aspx) to the msdn guid lines.